# How do I see all the function calls made from a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, jasmine

What is the appropriate layer at which I can interject and see the function call tree for the execution of a function?

I am trying to find to automatically generate unit tests that will mock function calls from a parent function? Are there any existing examples of this in the wild?

Comment: Have you tried using the Chrome Dev Tools debugger, you can stop on a breakpoint and see the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add console.log in each important point in this way you. Can see the execution way?